# Fullcalendar popover error: Bootstrap tooltips require Popper.js although this is already included

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter, fullcalendar

I am trying to add popovers to my fullcalendar within my codeignitor application, however, I keep getting the following error despite the mentioned library being clearly already included: Bootstrap tooltips require Popper.js.

Here is the order of my JavaScript libraries:

```
  <!-- JS Libs -->

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/moment.js')?>"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/fullcalendar-3.9.0/fullcalendar.js')?>"></script>
```

Here is the relevant section from my calendar configuration

```js
eventRender: function(eventObj, $el) {
        $el.popover({
            title: eventObj.title,
            content: eventObj.description,
            trigger: 'hover',
            placement: 'top',
            container: 'body'
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you forgot to close your first script correctly.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```